# Slow to call onLoadFinished

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite, android-loader

I'm using `Loader` and `Content Provider` to fill a listview with data from my database.
My problem is that, if I use the line below in my `Content Provider` to get data from database, the query and `onLoadFinished` is executed very fast (no problem to fill the listview):

```
Cursor c = this.mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE , null);
```

However, If I change the line to :

```
Cursor c = this.mDb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT D._id, D.Name, D.Icon FROM Plain A, Test B, Exercise C, Group D WHERE A.ID=1 AND B.PlainID=A._id AND B.TestID=C._id AND C.ExerciseID=D._id", null);
```

The query continues to run fast, but the application takes approximately 2s to call `onLoadFinished` and fill the listview.

why this delay if the cursor already executed query?

My Loader:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader");

    Uri uri = ContentProviderGroup.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = { Group.KEY_ROW_ID, Group.KEY_NAME, Group.KEY_ICON  };

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, // Parent activity context
            uri, // Table to query
            projection, // Projection to return
            null, // No selection clause
            null, // No selection arguments
            null); // Default sort order

    Log.d(TAG, "END onCreateLoader");

    return cursorLoader;

}
```

My Content Provider (query function):

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) { 

    Cursor cursor;

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == CODE){

        Log.d(TAG, "CALL SELECT");
        cursor = mCustomerDB.getGroup(selection, selectionArgs);
        Log.d(TAG, "END SELECT");

        return cursor;

    }else{          
        return null;
    }
}
```

My DBAdapter (getGroup function):

```
public Cursor getGroup(String selection, String[] selectionArgs){

    Log.d(TAG, "SELECT INIT");

            ///////  HERE I USE the rawQuery  /////////

    Log.d(TAG, "SELECT END");

    return c;

}
```

Thank You

Comment: to begin with, use `select`, not `rawQuery`

Comment: secondly, the cursor object only represent a projection on your data, it doesn't actually retrieve anything yet.

Comment: thirdly, do you have any index on your tables ?

Comment: also, if i recall, there is always an index on the _id column, so using it as a first argument in your comparison is probably better

Comment: Hi njzk2, I created the indexes and the problem persists. I have not found the function `select` to use it instead of `rawQuery`, but I think it's common to use `rawQuery` for this type of research. Tks

Comment: given that you are working on several tables at once, i guess it is, yes.

Comment: I would recommend that you audit your request outside of your app. Either use sqlite3 in adb shell or pull your database and open it from your computer. use the EXPLAIN (and EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN) command to have info on how sqlite actually does the query. it should also tell you if your index is actually used or not

Comment: the basics of query optimization in sqlite is documented here http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

Comment: Thanks for the link and tips, I am studying about optimization. But ... the interesting thing is that, if I do not use Loader and Contetent Provider (putting the results of a search in a ArrayList), the ListView is filled "little" faster.